# calling .cpp files from Objective-C class .m

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a few classes written in c++ which needs to be integrate with my iOS project written in Objective-C. I got a Mac (C++) project from my client to integrate with my project. I need to call the methods in .cpp class from Objective-C class with NSNotificationCenter or some other way which is better do it?

Comment: DLL. Filling this with characters so It fits the quota.

Comment: Rename .m into .mm and use c++ code.

Comment: I need to use the class not the code @Cy-4AH

Comment: Rename .m into .mm and use c++ classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a file with extension .mm you can use both Objective-C and C++ inside that one. It can quickly get messy so i usually try to keep the C++ touchpoints contains in a few .mm files so the whole thing won't be a mix of Objective-C and C++ and c code.